# The meaning of "Had to do with "

Tags: meaning, idioms

Would you tell me what does "***had to do with something***" mean?

I know what does "have to do with" mean but I can not get the meaning of "***"had to do with"***".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's the past tense of "has to do with". Meaning, it's logically connected to, or caused by, the other thing. For example,

> "Why do the sea levels rise and drop each day periodically? It has to do with the Moon's gravitation."

Answer (score 1):

**This asks about how something is involved with something else**

> "What do you have to do with this?"

In this case, the question is asking how someone is involved with something.

> "I don't have anything to do with this"

The person who is replying says that they are inot involved with the specified thing.

**Second example**

> "I don't know what he had to do with it"

The speaker doesn't know why the person was involved with "it", but they know that they were involved.